# CSS3 - How to make skew backgrounds for multiple sections?

Tags: html, css, skew

Good day, I'm in trouble with a layout that 4 sections have backgrounds in triangle shape and need skewing techniques, please take a look at this image : [image]
(each color represents the background), is it possible to do this in CSS?

I'd be appreciated if there's any help.

Comment: Have you done any work on it, if please do share!

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to do...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible using pure css you can achieve this using `transform`:

Here is the snippet:

```css
.edge--bottom {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.edge--bottom:after {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.edge--bottom:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
}

.edge--bottom--reverse {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.edge--bottom--reverse:after {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.edge--bottom--reverse:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.edge--top {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.edge--top:before {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.edge--top:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.edge--top--reverse {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.edge--top--reverse:before {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.edge--top--reverse:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.edge--both {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.edge--both:before,
.edge--both:after {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.edge--both:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.edge--both:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
}

.edge--both--reverse {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.edge--both--reverse:before,
.edge--both--reverse:after {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.edge--both--reverse:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.edge--both--reverse:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.-berry {
  background: #b52b4a;
}

.-blue {
  background: #41ade5;
}

.-orange {
  background: #de6628;
}

.-green {
  background: #5e9b42;
}

.block {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20% 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="block -berry edge--bottom">
  <h1>Bottom Angled Edge</h1>
</div>

<div class="block -blue edge--bottom--reverse">
  <h1>Bottom Angled Edge</h1>
  <p>Reversed</p>
</div>

<div class="block -berry edge--top">
  <h1>Top Angled Edge</h1>
</div>

<div class="block -blue edge--top--reverse">
  <h1>Top Angled Edge</h1>
  <p>Reversed</p>
</div>

<div class="block -orange edge--both">
  <h1>Top & Bottom Angled Edges</h1>
</div>

<div class="block -green edge--both--reverse">
  <h1>Top & Bottom Angled Edges</h1>
  <p>Reversed</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try base on your answer